# PySpark HBase/Phoenix integration

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-phoenix

I'm supposed to read Phoenix data into pyspark.

edit: 
I'm using Spark HBase converters:

Here is a code snippet:

```
port="2181"
host="zookeperserver"
keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"
valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"
cmdata_conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort":port, "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": "camel", "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns": "data:a"}
sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv,conf=cmdata_conf)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 547, in newAPIHadoopRDD
    jconf, batchSize)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.io.IOException: No table was provided.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase.getSplits(TableInputFormatBase.java:130)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!
/Tina

Answer (score 1):

Using spark phoenix plugin is the recommended approach.
please find details about phoenix spark plugin [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html)

Environment : tested with AWS EMR 5.10 , PySpark

Following are the steps

1. Create Table in phoenix https://phoenix.apache.org/language/
   Open Phoenix shell

   “/usr/lib/phoenix/bin/sqlline.py“

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableName;

   CREATE TABLE TableName (DOMAIN VARCHAR primary key);

   UPSERT INTO TableName (DOMAIN) VALUES('foo');
2. Download spark phoenix plugin jar
   download spark phoenix plugin jar from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-core/4.11.0-HBase-1.3
   you need phoenix--HBase--client.jar , i used phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-client.jar as per my phoenix and hbase version
3. From your hadoop home directory, setup the following variable:

   phoenix_jars=/home/user/apache-phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-bin/phoenix-4.11.0-HBase-1.3-client.jar
4. Start PySpark shell and add the dependency in Driver and executer classpath

   pyspark  --jars ${phoenix_jars} --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=${phoenix_jars}

--Create ZooKeeper URL ,Replace with your cluster zookeeper quorum, you can check from hbase-site.xml

```
emrMaster = "ZooKeeper URL" 

df = sqlContext.read \
.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
.option("table", "TableName") \
.option("zkUrl", emrMaster) \
.load() 

df.show()
df.columns
df.printSchema()
df1=df.replace(['foo'], ['foo1'], 'DOMAIN')
df1.show() 

df1.write \
  .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("table", "TableName") \
  .option("zkUrl", emrMaster) \
  .save()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this :
1) As Phoenix has a JDBC layer you can use Spark JdbcRDD to read data from Phoenix in Spark https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.html

2) Using Spark HBAse Converters:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/pythonconverters/HBaseConverters.scala
https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/python

Comment: I tried the second way, however Im getting an error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
: java.io.IOException: No table was provided.

Have you done this in PYSPARK?

Comment: Have you provided proper configurations to Spark newAPIHadoopRDD as follows:    
     

sparkconf = {
      "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": zookeeperhost, 
      "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable": sampletable,
      "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns": column}           hbase_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
      "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat",
      "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
      "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",
      keyConverter=keyConv,
      valueConverter=valueConv,
      conf=sparkconf)

Comment: Please try the above method i think you have not provided the table name in configuration.Also the value of keyConv and valueConv is examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter and examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter respectively

Comment: Please follow the below link for the example:https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/hbase_inputformat.py

Comment: Thank you Sachin!
However, I did all these steps.

1. I start pyspark with the needed jars, these are /hbase-0.90.1.jar, $SPARK_HOME/lib/spark-examples-1.3.1.2.3.0.0-2557hadoop2.7.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar

2. Then (in IPython Notebook):

from pyspark import SparkContext
port="2181"
host="hostname"

keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.ImmutableBytesWritableToStringConverter"

valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.HBaseResultToStringConverter"

Comment: cmdata_conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort":port, "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host, "hbase.mapreduce.inputtable”: "test", "hbase.mapreduce.scan.columns”: "f1:a"}

Comment: And when I run:
cmdata_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result",keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv,conf=cmdata_conf)

I receive the above error.

Comment: Is table in default namespace?Can you join chat